# log4j2 - Root contains an invalid element or attribute

Tags: java, maven, log4j2

Trying to use the sample XML file "Sample 1 / Log4j 2 XML configuration" from the page:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html

but it gives:

```
2013-09-25 02:22:59,182 ERROR Root contains an invalid element or attribute "AppenderRef"
```

Any ideas?

I am using this dependency in pom.xml,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta8</version>
</dependency>
```

and I use this inside the class:

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(App.class.getName());
```

and I specify the config file as follows:

```
java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml -jar target/project-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Comment: I don't see this error using the beta9 snapshot... it could be a fixed error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an error for 2.0-beta8, it is not present on 2.0-beta9

Here is the output using the beta9

```
        LOG.debug("Log4j Impl test started...");
        LOG.warn("  Log4j Impl test warn...");
        LOG.info("  Log4j Impl test info...");
        LOG.error("  Log4j Impl test error...");
...
2013-09-24 16:37:39,841 DEBUG [main] Log4jImplTest (Log4jImplTest.java:21) - Log4j Impl test started...
2013-09-24 16:37:39,843 WARN  [main] Log4jImplTest (Log4jImplTest.java:22) -   Log4j Impl test warn...
2013-09-24 16:37:39,843 INFO  [main] Log4jImplTest (Log4jImplTest.java:23) -   Log4j Impl test info...
2013-09-24 16:37:39,843 ERROR [main] Log4jImplTest (Log4jImplTest.java:24) -   Log4j Impl test error...
```

Here is the output using beta8:

```
2013-09-24 16:39:28,233 ERROR Root contains an invalid element or attribute "AppenderRef"
```

Comment: I tried it and yes that error does not appear in beta9. Thanks. One more question if you don't mind: If I don't use the switch `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml` it doesn't work. Where does it get the XML file? What is the default location of the XML file? If I don't specify it, it ignores my XML file.

Comment: Well if you use maven it should be in resources folder, otherwise it should be at class level "class path folder". Take a look to: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Comment: Whereever I put it, it is ignored. Yes I already had a look at that web page. Somehow my XML file is ignored. Anyway I will use the command line switch for now. Thank you.

Comment: As of beta-9 the preferred syntax for that element is AppenderRef, but for backwards compatibility there is also an alias called appender-ref. So older configs will still work with beta-9.  FYI, all config elements and attributes are case-insensitive. This changes is documented here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/changes-report.html#a2.0-beta9

Comment: @RemkoPopma Excellent, thanks. Then, basically the example will not apply to the beta8?

Comment: Correct: beta8 does not understand the new 'AppenderRef' syntax. It only understands 'appender-ref'.